# Chosen Incompatibility with jquery DataTable

Tags: datatables, jquery-chosen

I create a new header row for filter data in datatable.
For some columns, I want use a list of values that I can pick one and filter row data for that value.
For this, I would like to use the chosen plugin.

What happen is, when I define the datatable options scrollX or scrollY, the header change to a bad look and the dropdown of plugin stay beyond row data of datatable.
But if I remove this options, everything works fine - as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/sja9v7Lu/6/

Can some one help me resolve this?

Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                scrollX: true
        });

                    // Create filter row
        var filterTr = $('<tr></tr>');
        table.columns().every(function (colIndex, tLoopCounter, cLoopCounter) {
            var that = this, filterTd = null;

            if (this.header().cellIndex >= 0) {
                filterTd = $('<td></td>');
                if (colIndex == 2) {

                    var selectOptions = table.rows().data().pluck(colIndex).unique();

                    var select = $('<select id="office" class="chosen-select input-sm" />')
                    select.append('<option value="" />');

                    $.map(selectOptions, function (el, idx) {
                        var option = '<option value="' + el + '">' + el + '</option>';
                        select.append(option);
                    });

                    filterTd.append(select);

                    $('select#office', filterTd).chosen({
                        disable_search_threshold: 10,
                        allow_single_deselect: true,
                        width: "100%"
                    });

                    $('select#office', filterTd).on('change', function () {
                        var newValue = this.value;
                        if (that.search() !== newValue) {
                            that
                                .search(newValue)
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });
                }
                filterTr.append(filterTd);
            }
        });

        if ($('input, select', filterTr).length > 0)
            $('tr:last', table.table().header()).after(filterTr);

    });
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and switched to https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: I test it in an example and it needs some aditional work [bootstrap-select solution](https://jsfiddle.net/sja9v7Lu/7/). The best alternative I found was [select2](https://jsfiddle.net/sja9v7Lu/8/) but how I work in a project that already use chosen, I would like use it also here. But if I don't get a solution for chosen, I thinking use select2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it with the following css:

.dataTable .chosen-choices {z-index: 9999;}
.dataTable thead th .chosen-results li:first-child {margin-top: 30px;}

Edit: Margin top is 30px if div.chosen-choices has the same height as an individual li.search-choice, but as long as we continue choosing other options, div.chosen-choices grows up, and so must do the margin top. Finally, I get it with this code (selects are created dinamically):

$('body').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', '.yadcf-filter-wrapper select', function (evt, params) {
    var _height = $(evt.target).closest("div").find(".chosen-choices").height(); 
    $(evt.target).closest("div").find(".chosen-results li:first-child").attr("style", "margin-top: " + _height + "px");
});

- Working 100%, tested in Mozilla and Chrome